# Local coordinate system around a point such that vector fields are just partials

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the vector fields $V = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + xz \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $W = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + yz \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If $p\in \mathbb{R}^3$, does there exist a local coordinate system in a neighborhood of $p$ in which $V = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and $W = \frac{\partial}{\partial v}$? Namely, is there a diffeomorphism $\phi: U \rightarrow V$ from a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ to an open subset $V\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $V \mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and $W \mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial v}$?

My attempt:

I initially wanted to solve this problem by first considering that such map exists $\phi: U \rightarrow V$ such that $\phi(x,y,z) = (\phi_1(x,y,z), \phi_2(x,y,z), \phi_3(x,y,z)) =: (u,v,w)$ such that $d\phi_p(V) = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and $d\phi_p(W) = \frac{\partial}{\partial v}$. However, solving the system of equations seems pretty difficult.

I've seen a similar problem try to use Frobenius theorem (integrable iff involutive) but I don't seem to understand. I computed that $[V,W]=0$ so it is clear that $\mathcal{D} := \mathrm{span}\{ V,W \}$ is involutive and therefore integrable by Frobenius. Is this sufficient to say that there is a local coordinate system in a neighborhood of $p$ such that $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} = V$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} = W$?

Comment: This is more basic than Frobenius. All you need is commuting flows and the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry if this is an extremely basic question. If I recall correctly, a distribution being integrable means that it is spanned by coordinate vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}, \dots, \frac{\partial }{\partial x^k}$ right? However, this doesn't necessarily immediately imply that we can find a local coordinate system around $p$ such that $V= \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and $W = \frac{\partial}{\partial v}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin As of now, it seems to me that Frobenius theorem tells us that the distribution spanned by $V$ and $W$ is equal to a distribution spanned by two coordinate vector fields, but it won't give $V= \frac{\partial }{\partial u}$ and $W=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there exist local coordinates for which $V=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and $W=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$. This follows from Theorem 9.4.6 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. We just have to check that $V$ and $W$ are linearly independent and commute for every $p\in\mathbb{R}^3$. It is clear that $V$ and $W$ are linearly independent, so I'll just show commutativity. Working locally, write $V=V^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ and $W=W^j\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$. We know that
$$[V,W]=\left(V(W^j)-W(V^j)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}.$$

For this, we have
$$V(W^3)-W(V^3)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+xz\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)(yz)-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+yz\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)(xz)=xzy-yzx=0.$$
I'll leave it to you to verify that $V(W^j)-W(V^j)=0$ for $j=1,2$. This shows that $[V,W]=0$, so we're done.

**EDIT**: It seems like you've already determined that $[V,W]=0$, so I'll add the linear independence argument (which I'm sure you already see). Indeed, the (global) coordinate representation of $V$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
xz
\end{pmatrix}$,
which is clearly not a scalar multiple of $[W]_\mathcal{B}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ yz\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Thank you for also citing the Theorem in Lee!!! This was super helpful.

Comment: Of course - best of luck!